# register_sidebar not display the widget with specific id

Tags: wordpress

I've registered in `functions.php` a `footer-ads` sitebar:

```
register_sidebar(array( 'name' => 'Footer Ads','id' => 'footer-ads', 'description' => "Footer ads area", 'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">','after_widget' => '</div>','before_title' => '<h3 class="group"><span>','after_title' => '</span></h3>'));
```

if I go inside `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Widget` the sidebar isn't displayed, but if I change the id as `footer-ads-0` for example, I can see the sitebar displayed, why happen this?

Comment: Because `footer-ads` already registered..

Comment: @ChandraKumar but I doesn't have any other sidebar registered with this id

Answer (score 0):

Try to unset id before register sidebar: `unregister_sidebar('footer-ads');`

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_footer_sidebar' );
function add_footer_sidebar() {

    unregister_sidebar('footer-ads'); 
    /** I have looked for the ID of the sidebar by looking at        
     *  the source code in the admin.. and saw the widget's id="footer-ads"
     */ 
    register_sidebar(array( 'name' => 'Footer Ads','id' => 'footer-ads', 'description' => "Footer ads area", 'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">','after_widget' => '</div>','before_title' => '<h3 class="group"><span>','after_title' => '</span></h3>')); 
}
```

Comment: unfortunately same problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found the problem, there is no bug in my php code for sitebar registration, I was wondering why changing the id from `footer-ads` to anything else will working.

The problem is caused by AdBlock and relative plugins that kill the ads that insert inside the html structure some css that will remove the `footer-ads`, now the sitebar working good.